# SELECT * WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, not-exists

I think I'm going down the right path with this one... Please bear with me as my SQL isn't the greatest

I'm trying to query a database to select everything from one table where certain cells don't exist in another. That much doesn't make a lot of sense but I'm hoping this piece of code will

```
SELECT * from employees WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM eotm_dyn)
```

So basically I have one table with a list of employees and their details. Then another table with some other details, including their name. Where there name is not in the eotm_dyn table, meaning there is no entry for them, I would like to see exactly who they are, or in other words, see what exactly is missing.

The above query returns nothing, but I know there are 20ish names missing so I've obviously not gotten it right.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You didn't join the table in your query.

Your original query will always return nothing unless there are no records at all in `eotm_dyn`, in which case it will return everything.

Assuming these tables should be joined on `employeeID`, use the following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    employees e
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  null 
        FROM    eotm_dyn d
        WHERE   d.employeeID = e.id
        )
```

You can join these tables with a `LEFT JOIN` keyword and filter out the `NULL`'s, but this will likely be less efficient than using `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: I need "WHERE NOT EXISTS" twice a year, and I always forget how to exactly use it. Thanks - this example will be bookmarked now.

Comment: Could someone please give a reference for "LEFT JOIN + NULL filter is less efficient than NOT EXISTS"? It can be obvious, but I never saw that in the docs. Thanks.

Comment: @toni07 Actually, that is a legend. LEFT JOIN wins. https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/   .. Quassnoi's blog is always a helpful resource.

Comment: how would I use this in a HAVING clause? aka `group by X having exist [row with employeeID = e.id]`

Comment: @blauhirn: just like that

Answer (score 93):

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM eotm_dyn)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM eotm_dyn WHERE eotm_dyn.name = employees.name)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM employees LEFT OUTER JOIN eotm_dyn ON eotm_dyn.name = employees.name WHERE eotm_dyn IS NULL
```

Comment: NB! `NOT IN` does not work as expected if `name`has `null`values. Watch from 36min 20sec in the video [SESSION: 10 Query Tuning Techniques Every SQL Programmer Should Know (Kevin Kline, Aaron Bertrand)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUCxQkFoqpw).

Comment: you can flter with "Where name IS Not NULL" in sub query

Comment: In addition, ```NOT IN``` is not as fast as ```NOT EXISTS```

Answer (score 13):

You can do a LEFT JOIN and assert the joined column is NULL.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM employees a LEFT JOIN eotm_dyn b on (a.joinfield=b.joinfield) WHERE b.name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT * from employees
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM eotm_dyn)
```

Never returns any records unless `eotm_dyn` is empty.  You need to some kind of criteria on `SELECT name FROM eotm_dyn` like

```
SELECT * from employees
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM eotm_dyn WHERE eotm_dyn.employeeid = employees.employeeid
)
```

assuming that the two tables are linked by a foreign key relationship.  At this point you could use a variety of other options including a LEFT JOIN.  The optimizer will typically handle them the same in most cases, however.

Answer (score 4):

You can also have a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354002/mysql-select-where-not-in-table). That user reported that using a join provided better performance than using a sub query.