# select from column where value in a list or no such column

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

Ok here's my task

I have a list of lenders like this

```
lender  name
1       lender 1
2       some other lender
```

and I have a list of states like this

```
lender  state
1       AK
1       WY
1       NY
2       AZ
2       FL
```

so i have an area, for example FL, i need to select all lenders where state = "FL" OR where state is not defined at all (this would mean ANY state)

I can't figure out how to do the second part (where state is not defined). Any help to figure out?

Thanks

Comment: OR state is NULL ? or do you want to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915643/select-where-not-exists

Comment: you are right, thanks for advice too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from lenders where state='FL' or state is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "undefined" fields are `NULL`, you could simply add `OR state IS NULL` to your query.