# How do I properly use NOT EXISTS for MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display a list of items that do not already exist in another table. For instance:

```
usertable:

uid
name
email

othertable:
uid
```

I'm trying to filter out users that already exist in the other table, so when I display the usertable, it will only show users that are not in the othertable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL "NOT IN" query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915643/select-where-not-exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOT EXIST in mysql is completely another thing from what you want to do. **UPDATE: This is not true!** (thanks for pointing out)

I understand you want to select all records that are in usertable but not in othertable, right?

```
SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE uid NOT in (SELECT uid FROM othertable)
```

**UPDATE** In case you want to check all the fields in the row, not only the ID, you can use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM usertable
WHERE field1, field2, fieldN NOT IN
(SELECT field1, field2, fieldN FROM othertable)
```

Comment: That is correct! Thanks! Am I also able to add a WHERE clause in the second select?

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is a perfectly valid approach for the case.

Comment: @diesel Sure, the second query is a normal query returning a set of results that will be used for the `... IN ...` filter

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter damn, I love learning new things.. I always thought `NOT EXISTS` was only for `CREATE TABLE` and such..

Comment: That's `IF NOT EXISTS`. See here what you can actually do with `WHERE (NOT) EXISTS`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: yep.. I just googled that too :) anyways, it looks more readable (to me) by just using the sub-query, doesn't it? Plus, how would you write the "an equal record with different id exists" thing, using `NOT EXISTS` ..?

Answer (score 2):

This would be simpler with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM   usertable u
LEFT   JOIN othertable o USING (uid)
WHERE  o.uid IS NULL
```

If you want to have `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   usertable u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM othertable o
    WHERE o.uid = u.uid
    )
```