# Select over multiple tables MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables 'users', 'friends', 'friendsrequests'.

'Users' contains an id, a firstname and a lastname, 'friends' and 'friendsrequests' both contain users_id_a and users_id_b.

When I search for new friends, I select id's where firstname is LIKE :whatever or lastname LIKE :whatever. However, I want to exclude those id's which are present in the other two tables.

I know how to solve this via application logic, but I also know I shouldn't do this. I know I shouldn't chain the SELECT statements and that I should use joins.

Answer (score 2):

You've answered your own question in that you know you can use `joins`. There are plenty of examples available here on how to do a join in MySQL.

There are several join types but the one you require in this instance is probably a LEFT OUTER. You could do a then do the filtering on the field on the other two tables by using a `IS NULL`. So what this is doing is joining on the additional tables regardless if there is any data in those tables. Using a WHERE `IS NULL` to filter out those that are present.

Rather than using joins you could take a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` approach. This logic might be more up your street if you're not familiar with SQL joins. 
An example might be:

```
SELECT * FROM FRIENDS f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM friendsrequests fr WHERE f.user_id = fr.user_id)
```

Some examples can be found here:
[SELECT * WHERE NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915643/select-where-not-exists)

Another approach in using the `IN` statement or specifically the `WHERE NOT IN (SELECT ...)`

Hopefully this will guide you if you're still stuck post your exact sql schema and the requirement on a site like http://sqlfiddle.com/ and you'll more likely get more specific response.

Comment: As you can tell I am by no means an expert on databases, but I read somewhere that using SELECT ... WHERE NOT IN (SELECT...) is discouraged, since this would be very slow on large tables. Is this true?

Comment: I wouldn't say it would be "very slow" in comparison. It depends on query and table size from experience - In real world systems for most queries you'd be hard-pressed to notice any performance difference.  Just be aware of it. Here's a good article comparing the three. http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/ Reason I mention the different types is that it can be clearer understanding the queries intention.