# Select from a table the ones that don't have a relationship with another table

Tags: mysql

The specific problem is listing the names of the teachers that never graded.

I have 'teachers' table with the columns 'Name' and 'ID'.
And 'grades' table with the column 'IDTeacher' and 'Grade'.

Don't get why this doesn't work:

```
Select Name from teachers where not exists(Select * from grades, teachers)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SELECT \* WHERE NOT EXISTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915643/select-where-not-exists)

Comment: Both Dognose & Gordon Linoff have the correct ways of doing it. The reason your doesn't work is that your inner select doesn't have any criteria to match it to the outer one as well as you are doing a implied full outer join in it, so the inner select will always return rows unless you don't have any rows in both grades and teachers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query does *work*, it just doesn't do what you think it should.  The subquery creates a cartesian product between the two tables.  If both tables have rows, then the cartesian product has rows and the `where` clause will always be true.

You can take this approach, but you need a correlated subquery:

```
Select Name
from teachers t
where not exists (Select 1 from grades g where g.idteacherid = t.id);
```

Note that this query only has one table in the subquery.

There are other ways to write this query, but this seems to be the approach you are heading in.  And, `not exists` is a very reasonable approach.

Answer (score 6):

You can just join it with the grades table and use the ones where the join returns "null" for the right side:

```
SELECT
   name
from
   teachers t
LEFT JOIN
   grades g
on
   t.teacher = g.teacher
WHERE
   ISNULL(g.teacher)
```

edit: Thought about a right join instead, but no, the right join might not work, if the teacher has **no** entry in the grades table. (Then you would miss him completely, even if he is in the `teacher` table)

You could also use `WHERE IN` for this:

```
SELECT 
  name 
FROM 
  teachers 
WHERE 
  name 
NOT IN (SELECT name from grades)
```

**BUT** the MySQL Optimizer will rewrite this to exactly the correlated subquery @Gordon Linoff has written. Using `WHERE NOT IN` is just easier to read imho.

Comment: Maybe I look at this graphic more than I should. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16598900/3403036 :D

Comment: Do you know how I could solve it with not exists? thanks it works

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro See Gordon Linoffs answer for a solution with `not exists`