# I want to query a moodle database to pull records to a sync'd account, but 'Where NOT EXISTS" is returning a syntax error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench, not-exists

I have been plugging away at this and I am really at a loss for what I'm messing up. I am using My SQL workbench and sending queries to a mariadb. The original function I am working with, returns records just fine, however they pull in all of them (of which there are 1000+). Ideally the function would only return new records instead of all of them (hence no delete). I am trying to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` however SQL is returning error code 1064. Sample code below:

```
SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS 
usr1.email 
 , case when ccm.course = 7 then 'CourseComplete' 
  when ccm.course = 10 then 'Course1' when ccm.course = 4 then 'Course1CourseComplete' else 'other' end as coursecompleted 
 , course 
 ,  date_add(from_unixtime(timecompleted), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) as CompletionDate 
 FROM  moodledb.m_course_completions ccm 
 inner join m_user usr1 
 on ccm.userid = usr1.id 
 where timecompleted is not null and ccm.course in (4,7,10) order by 4 desc
```

In addition I've tried alternate placements for the where not exists function, but they all return the same error1064. Would a different operator work better? Can goku defeat this new foe?  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` are used in subqueries. Where you are trying to use it does not appear to be a format that is valid or supported. What exactly are you trying to check for not existing?

Comment: remove `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, replace join with`LEFT join m_user usr1 
 on ccm.userid = usr1.id WHERE usr1 IS NULL AND ...`

Comment: @danblack 
Thank you! It looks like I was able to get around the 1064, i got an new error but I think ill be able to make this work. Again thank you!

Comment: ops. obviously should be `...usr1.id IS NULL...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT \* WHERE NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915643/select-where-not-exists)