# how to do a SQL Join that returns the rows that are not present in my table 2

Tags: sql, join

I want to run a query between my two tables and returns the results to me the lines that are not present in my table 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table1 
         left join table2 
         on table1.id=table2.id 
         where table2.id is null
```

Comment: sorry, the same answer at the same time. Do you want me to delete mine?

Comment: @Macro: What for sorry? No problem. This is natural on SO

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354002/mysql-select-where-not-in-table).
I copied the code:

```
select * from A left join B on A.x=B.y where B.y is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table1_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1)
```