# MYSQL Join puzzle: inner and left join at the same time

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

```
Schools
Teachers
Courses
XRefSchoolsTeachers
XRefCoursesTeachers
```

Now I am trying to get the list of all the teachers at the college the course is offered at, which are NOT teaching that course. So far I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM Courses
INNER JOIN XRefSchoolsTeachers
    ON Courses.SchoolID = XRefSchoolsTeachers.SchoolID
```

which gives me the IDs of all the teachers at the school which the course is offered at, but now I need to remove all the IDs of teachers which are not against the ID of that course in `XRefCoursesTeachers`. I looked at [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354002/mysql-select-where-not-in-table) about how to remove things not on another list, and I need a left join for that. But I feel like I need an inner join too so that I only get teachers from that school which are not on the list already ><

e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM Courses
INNER JOIN XRefSchoolsTeachers
    ON Courses.SchoolID = XRefSchoolsTeachers.SchoolID
LEFT JOIN XRefCoursesTeachers
    ON (XRefCoursesTeachers.TeacherID = XRefSchoolsTeachers.TeacherID
     AND XRefCoursesTeachers.CourseID = Courses.ID)
WHERE Courses.ID = ? AND XRefSchoolsTeachers.TeacherID IS NULL
```

will give me all the teachers at any other course at any other school - not what I want. I want all the teachers which could teach *this* course but are not.

It is like I need an inner join on the `XRefCourseTeachers.CourseID = Courses.ID`, and then a left join on the same instance of `XRefCourseTeachers` using `TeacherID` so that I can pick out the `NULL` results. But I don't get how to do this.

How is this possible? Am I taking the correct approach?

Comment: It seems you are missing a table - CoursesSchools?

Comment: Not quite. It turns out that each course can only be taught at a single school, and so the `Courses` table includes a `SchoolID` column. It might be better design to have that extra table, but for now its simply a column.

Comment: No need of re-posting the same solution as given by Clodoaldo. Rather you should vote and accept his solution

Comment: @sami Actually his solution doesn't work and isn't the same as the one I posted. Pls see the comment I posted on his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM Courses
INNER JOIN XRefSchoolsTeachers
    ON Courses.SchoolID = XRefSchoolsTeachers.SchoolID
LEFT JOIN XRefCoursesTeachers
    ON (XRefCoursesTeachers.TeacherID = XRefSchoolsTeachers.TeacherID AND XRefCoursesTeachers.CourseID = Courses.ID)
WHERE 
        XRefCoursesTeachers.TeacherID IS NULL
    AND
        Cousers.ID = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Courses
INNER JOIN XRefSchoolsTeachers
    ON Courses.SchoolID = XRefSchoolsTeachers.SchoolID
left join XRefCoursesTeachers
    on XRefCoursesTeachers.TeacherID = XRefSchoolsTeachers.TeacherID
where 
    XRefCoursesTeachers.TeacherID is null
    and
    Cousers.ID = ?
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM Courses
INNER JOIN XRefSchoolsTeachers
    ON Courses.SchoolID = XRefSchoolsTeachers.SchoolID
where 
    XRefCoursesTeachers.TeacherID not in (
        select TeacherID
        from XRefCoursesTeachers
        where XRefCoursesTeachers.CourseID = Courses.ID
    )
    and
    Courses.ID = ?
```

Comment: Of course!!~ I forgot inner join can also be done in the `WHERE` clause :D Thanks

Comment: On closer inspection, your first expression is basically what I stated in the question, and it doesn't work