# Cakephp Find removed rows of two joined tables

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have table A and table B and they are both joined through a relationship. table B has a foreign key of table A's key. Table A is joined when the program runs because it is dynamic and could reside in any database. How would I find all the rows in table B that are no longer found in table A?

```
For ex.
Starting out we have
table A     table B
4              4
3              3
5              5
```

later that evening

```
table A deleted some rows

table A        table B
NULL              4
3                 3
NULL              5
```

I want to get the keys 4,5 so that I can tell what was deleted.

Comment: tip: use real names, real examples - ask about real problems. And as far as php logic goes - you need to know/understand the sql query you need. If you are not sure, you're asking the wrong question :).

Comment: this is a real example

Comment: you have a table named a and a table named b each with one field? I don't believe you - sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use mysql where not in table. I would just use cakephp query method versus find. Here is a topic that already has been answered: [Where not in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354002/mysql-select-where-not-in-table)

Comment: does that also work with tables that are not in the same database?

Comment: as long as the account has the appropriate permissions yes

Comment: reference material: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/mysql-join-between-tables-in-2-different-databases

Comment: I know this wasn't in my original question, but does this work the same for tables in different databases and different servers?