# join two tables and select records only if NOT in table 2

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to join two tables and only print records from table 1 where the rec_number is NOT in table 2.

```
table 1
name        rec_number
john smith   123
Bob jonson   345
etc

Table 2 
Bob jonson   345
etc
```

What is the query in php that would do this so the query only gives me John smith, not bob jonson.
is it:

```
    $query = "select * from table1
    left join rec_number on table1.rec_number = table2.rec_number";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql select where not in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354002/mysql-select-where-not-in-table)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query

```
select 
t1.*
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
on t2.rec_number = t1.rec_number
where t2.rec_number IS NULL
```

Comment: Also known as an [antijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29).

Comment: here is a nice article with examples of different joins . http://www.mysqldiary.com/mysql-left-join/

Answer (score 0):

Beside the `left join` mentioned by Abhik, you could also use a subselect:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM table2);
```