# Excluding records between tables

Tags: mysql

take a look to the following tables.

Table `spawns`:

```
+----------+---+----+----+--+
| id_spawn | position | map |
+----------+---+----+----+--+
|        1 |        1 |   1 |
|        2 |        2 |   1 |
+----------+----------+-----+
```

Table `games`;

```
+---------+-----+
| id_game | map |
+---------+-----+
|       1 |   1 |
|       2 |   1 |
|       3 |   1 |
|       4 |   1 |
|       5 |   1 |
+---------+-----+
```

Table `warriors`:

```
+---------+------+----------+
| id_join | game | position |
+---------+------+----------+
|       1 |    1 |        2 |
+---------+------+----------+
```

I am trying to get `position` from `spawns` that have not been used in `warriors` giving a specific `game`. At first attempt I did:

```
select s.position
from spawns s
left join games g on g.map = s.map
left join warriors w on w.game = g.id_game
where s.position not in(w.position)
and g.id_game = 1;
```

> The query returns `1` as expected

However, for `game = 5` I was expecting 2 available positions, but empty result received.  I am assuming the db engine does not find a relation between `games` and `warriors` because the game has not warriors to compare. So, how can I get these positions?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see `s.game` in the table ?

Comment: Thank you. It was a mistake when transcribed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, for a given `gameid` you want to return the `positions` in the `spawns` table that do not have corresponding `positions` in the `warriors` table?  If so, here's one option using an `outer join` / `null` check.

```
select s.position
from spawns s
    join games g on g.map = s.map
    left join warriors w on w.game = g.id_game and s.position = w.position
where g.id_game = 1 and w.id_join is null
```

---

BTW, another common approach is to use `not exists`.  While most databases can optimize that approach, `mysql` seems to have trouble with it.  Here are some good posts on the matter:

- http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/
- [Mysql select where not in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354002/mysql-select-where-not-in-table)

Comment: Fantastic! I have noticed that you removed `not in()` function, it looks very clean query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` so as to exclude positions from spawns that have been used in warriors given a specific game:

```
SELECT s.position
FROM spawns AS s
INNER JOIN games AS g ON g.map = s.map
WHERE g.id_game = ? AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM warriors AS w
                  WHERE w.game = g.id_game AND w.position = s.position)
```